# Connecting own strategy with another

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

so I just want to connect my own strategy with another (in this case with the MACD strategy). So at every time when my strategy markes a candle (alert) and the MACD strategy marks this candle, or one candle before or after, my new strategy (these two connected) should give me an alert. How can I do this? I´m really new to this.
Tia

Answer (score 0):

In strategy tester, there is a tab trading panel. You can use those brokers for direct integration I think. List also contains tradingview paper trading account which can be used for forward testing.

There is also option of web hooks in alerts. If your broker provides APIs through which you can place orders, you can probably make use of this and write an integration layer probably?